# What results does showStatistics throw me in scenekit?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, scene

I don't have much experience in scenekit, I'm actually working in project in a using scenekit, I'm creating sceneView  and adding configurations for my project, but I don't know what's the 'showsStatistics' propiety meaning

```
var sceneView: SCNView!  
var scena = SCNScene()  
var nodeInitial = SCNNode()  
var arrayNodes = [SCNNode] ()  


override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  
        nodeInitial = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/world.dae")!  
        for node in nodeInitial.rootNode.ChildNodes as [SCNNode] {  
               arrayNode.append(node)  
        }  
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(arrayNode.last!)  
        sceneView.scene = scene  
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true  
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true  
}
```

The results throw at me:

[image: SCNView statistics]

The part of left I understand that it makes reference to model propieties, but the part of right I don't know and every time I add elements it increases values and when I delete all the nodes it also increases